# Dynamic Content in content builder - Profile attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, subscriber-key

For one of my clients I am trying to create a dynamic content block for the standard email footers. Since this client is sending emails in more then 70 languages, the desired solution is to have one drag and drop content block that will always display the right language for each customer. The block is dynamic based on two fields:

countryCode
languageCode

I have already set up a dynamic content block which has all the different combinations of countryCode and languageCode. In order to test the block I have created testdata manually, which has 3 fields. A sample row would look something like this:

Emailaddress | countryCode | languageCode 
myemail+(languageCode-countryCode)@gmail.com | EN | EN

I created a test data extension where Emailaddress is the primary key, which relates to the Subscriber key in All subscribers. The Data extension contains a record for all the different combinations of countryCode and languageCode.

the languageCode and countryCode fields are set up as profile attributes in email studio. There is also a link between these set up in Contact Builder.

When I tried to send a test to the data extension I did receive all of the emails, but all of them had the default English footer. The records do show up in the All subscribers list and All Contacts, but the values for languageCode and CountryCode remain empty. it does seem that Marketing Cloud does not understand the relationship there. I am a bit confused why Marketing Cloud isn't directly updating these profile attributes, is there something I'm missing here?

Would gladly appreciate any help!

Comment: When you created the dynamic content block which data source did you chose ProfileAttributes or DataExtension? How are you sending, did you implement these values in a dataextension to send or do you just have some email addresses in there with the corresponding languages values in the profile attributes?

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick The Dynamic Content block should take it's values from the Profile Attributes, so it makes sense that it's showing the default because the fields are not being populated through the Data Extension that I created.  First I tried a test send to the entire test data extension through Content Builder. When that didn't succeed I suspected that the values didn't update because it's a test send.  In order to replicate an actual send I tried an user initiated send to the same data extension.

Comment: Profile Attributes work on a centralized set of columns. You can find those inside email studio - Profile management. When you send to particular emails that have not been send to you have to set the values for these subscribers. You can do this inside the all Subscribers tab and search for a particular subscriber and see its attributes there. I believe you have not set the values there (but i might be wrong).

Comment: I haven't set specific values for either languageCode or countryCode indeed. What I expected to happen was that Marketing cloud would pull these in All Subscribers from the Data Extension that I created, but it seems that it is only taking the Emailaddress field and leaves the other values blank.                                 Is it technically possible to update the profile attributes through a data upload in a data extension?

Comment: Thats correct. When you want to set profile attributes you need to import these with a file import activity inside automation studio and match the files columns to the profile attributes of the subscriber [when you are not connected to a salesforce product like salescloud or service cloud] But thats only if you want to use the profile attributes (you could also change and go for dataextensions only)

Comment: Thanks @JohannesSchapdick, that makes sense. I am however a bit hessitant to use a Data Extention to create the footer. If we send out an actual email we will upload the data for this send into a data extension, which will also have the countryCode and languageCode field to determine which languages the customer gets. I think for the footer though it will lookup the data extension that I used to create the dynamic footer, instead of taking the values from the "send data extension". Which would result in to customers receiving the default footer instead. Am I correct on this?

Comment: You are wrong on this. If you base this on a dataextension the fieldnames must exactly match those you have defined in your source. The "SOURCE" of the dynamic content block is not really a dataextension. It just tells from which column the value should come from. It will always take the data from the sending data extension. When the fields will be named in the same way it will be working. When the sending dataextension does not include the right values or no values or the wrong column names for these "right named columns you chose" than it will get the default footer.

Comment: That sounds great, in that case I will rebuild the ruleset based on the Data Extension instead of profile attributes. Will do some testing and will let you know, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out finally. Dragging the Dynamic Content block in a template works. By doing it this way, a piece of Ampscript is being generated by Content builder, basically including IFELSE statements for each different variation. Thank you for the help @Johannes Schapdick!

Answer (score 0):

Profiles Attributes do not get set when you send to a dataextension. When you are sending emails to a dataextension, the values from language end country will not be transferred to the profile attributes. The only stuff that will be created is the subscriberkey for that particular email address if you have set the connection SubscriberKey relates to "email" in your sending dataextension.

To cover dynamic profiles like this you either have to change your dynamic content block to dataextension attributes and always include the columns with the corresponding values into the sending dataextension

OR

you have to make sure that your subscriber have been set these values on the subscriber level. The only option that i currently know of that sets these attributes in mass is a file import activity with correct matching to the subscriber profile attributes.

Comment: I have tried to replicate the process as described using Data Extension values  instead of profile attributes, but it's not working. I'm still getting default footers. Thus, no luck so far. I guess i'll leave it for now, and get back at it tomorrow.

Comment: Figured it out finally. Dragging the Dynamic Content block in a template works. By doing it this way, a piece of Ampscript is being generated by Content builder, basically including IFELSE statements for each different variation. Thank you for the help @Johannes Schapdick!